# How to Delete Firebase DataBase from onClick listener of Button

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, onclick

I'm using Recycle Adapter Class to show the Firebase Data in my app which contains the list of books that are available to purchase.

But once a book is sold, I want the user will be able to delete that book and will eventually delete from Firebase Database also on onClick of Button.
How can I do this?

Here is my Firebase Data Structure:

[image]
Here is RecycleAdapter Class

Here is my Adapter Data Class:

```
public class SubjectBooksAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubjectBooksAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    ArrayList<Books> bookslist;
    CardView cv;
    FirebaseAuth fauth;
    FirebaseDatabase database;
    DatabaseReference dbreference;
    Books b;

    public SubjectBooksAdapter(ArrayList<Books> bookslist){
        this.bookslist = bookslist;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.layout,parent,false);
        return new MyViewHolder(v);
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView bookName,bookAuthor,bookDesc,bookPrice,bookCall;
        ImageView iv;
        Button delete;

        MyViewHolder(final View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.my_card_view);

            iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

            database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
            dbreference = database.getReference("books");
            bookName = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookName);
            bookAuthor = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookAuthor);
            bookDesc = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookDesc);
            bookPrice = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookPrice);
            bookCall = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.bookCall);
            fauth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

            delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        dbreference = database.getReference("books");

        b = bookslist.get(position);
        holder.bookName.setText(b.getBname());
        holder.bookAuthor.setText(b.getBauthor());
        holder.bookDesc.setText(b.getBdesc());
        holder.bookPrice.setText("Rs. "+b.getPrice());
        holder.bookCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Log.e("Current user is ", fauth.getCurrentUser().getEmail());
                b = bookslist.get(position);
                String[] arr = {b.getSelleremail(),b.getSellername(),b.getBname(),b.getBauthor()};
                //Log.e("Seller is ",b.getSellername());
                Intent in = new Intent(v.getContext(),Chat.class);
                in.putExtra("seller",arr);
                v.getContext().startActivity(in);
            }
        });
        Glide.with(cv.getContext()).load(Uri.parse(b.getPics())).placeholder(R.drawable.bshelf).error(R.drawable.bshelf).into(holder.iv);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return bookslist.size();
    }
}
```

And I'm using this in upload class to push Data in Firebase:

```
 String bookid = dbreference.child("books").child(item).push().getKey();
                dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid).setValue(b);
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `removeValue()` method directly on the reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```
        DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bname");

                                    driverRef.removeValue();

    if you delete whole database
    use this

      DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    driverRef.removeValue();

//---------------------Use on Button click Listener--------

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
Button button=findViewById(R.id.btn);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        DatabaseReference driverRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("bname");

        driverRef.removeValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: But How do I setonClick listener as I have implemented                 delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete); but when i set onClicklistener like this delete.setOnClickListener(this); it gives me error. please help.

Comment: I have sent again answer

Comment: @VishalSharma your code block has low readability and it makes it hard for reusing it in the future. can you make it more readable so it would make a better impact for other developers? here is something you can do: correct your code alignment and indentation and comment the parts that is not actual code(like the second line of your code). thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you know the id of that book you should be able to remove the child with that id reference.

You have to implement the click listener as you did before with **holder.bookCall.setOnClickListener(...);**

**Code:**

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            dbreference.child("books").child(bookId).remove();
        }
    });
```

I hope it helps you.

Comment: But How do I setonClick listener as I have implemented                 delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete); but when i set onClicklistener like this delete.setOnClickListener(this); it gives me error.  please help.

Answer (score 2):

You can put `null` against your bookid to remove it from it from database.

```
dbreference.child("books").child(bookId).setValue(null);
```

Comment: But How do I setonClick listener as I have implemented                 delete = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.delete); but when i set onClicklistener like this delete.setOnClickListener(this); it gives me error.

Answer (score 1):

This code will remove a book you want, just get the id of the book and place inside onClickListener:

```
dbreference.child("books").child(item).child(bookid).removeValue();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
dbref.child("books").child("Computer Science").child(key).removeValue();
```